# Mobile safari error when scrolling WHEN THE ADDRESS BAR IS FROM THE TOP

Tags: reactjs, mobile, safari

Mobile safari error when scrolling WHEN THE ADDRESS BAR IS FROM THE TOP

When you scroll up and down as if the downloaded content is deleted and loaded again. (THIS BUG IS ONLY IF THE ADDRESS BAR IS FROM THE TOP )

When you scroll up and down as if the downloaded content is deleted and loaded again. (THIS BUG IS ONLY IF THE ADDRESS BAR IS FROM THE TOP )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByVou.png)